# Android - Make a LinearLayout which contains a ListView scrollable

Tags: android, listview, scrollview, android-linearlayout

I know that everyone's recommended that we should never use `ListView` and `ScrollView` together, and I totally agree. However, I'm currently stuck with a very simple pattern like 8tracks' profile page (as shown in the image below), which include an area for the user profile and a list of mixes they made. So basically, it's desirable that users can just scroll down that page, which means the profile part will get on top of the screen and gradually out of view, and at the same time the below list is scrolled too:

[image]

However, at the moment, all I can do is to include a `ListView` within a `LinearLayout`, just like my sketch here.

[image]

With this design, I can only scroll the list down, while the profile area stays at the same place, which sucks. So I'm looking for any idea to make the whole page scrollable, not just the list. Please help and thanks.

**EDITED**: I'm sorry for the misleading question. My problem is even more complicated because the content of the tabs are not just `ListView` - some tab contains `LinearLayout` or `GridView` instead. Again, what I want to achieve is to make the whole page scrollable, but `ScrollView` can't help because if the content of a tab is a `ListView` or `GridView`, these views will be collapsed and more importantly - this goes against the design rule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this is late, but I'm the current developer for 8tracks. The (old) 2.x app you have shown above is being rewritten, but I can show you what the old dev did for the profile page.

Before going into that I must say that this is not the best way to do this, but the 8tracks app (2.x) is old.

So back to the code…
The `ProfileActivity` contains a `ProfileFragment`.

The main layout you see with the Follow button (and the profile image) is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <!-- Image, name, location -->

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="10dip" >

        <com.gdub.widget.ImageViewClickable
            android:id="@+id/dj_avatar"
            android:layout_width="110dip"
            android:layout_height="110dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
            android:background="@drawable/default_avatar_max200"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

        <com.gdub.widget.CollapsingTextView
            android:id="@+id/dj_location"
            style="@style/mix.counts"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dip"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/dj_avatar" />

        <ViewSwitcher
            android:id="@+id/profile_action_btn"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/dj_location"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/dj_avatar" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/follow_btn"
                style="@style/white_button"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/follow" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/edit_profile_btn"
                style="@style/white_button"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/edit_profile" />
        </ViewSwitcher>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/dj_bio"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="-25dip"
        android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
        android:lineSpacingExtra="2dip"
        android:paddingLeft="10dip"
        android:paddingRight="10dip"
        android:textColor="@color/default_text"
        android:textSize="15sp" />

    <include
        android:id="@+id/profile_tabs"
        layout="@layout/profile_tabs" />

</LinearLayout>
```

And profile_tabs…

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:visibility="gone"
  android:orientation="horizontal">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/profile_mixes_button"
        layout="@layout/profile_tab" />

    <include
        android:id="@+id/profile_followers_button"
        layout="@layout/profile_tab"  />

    <include
        android:id="@+id/profile_following_button"
        layout="@layout/profile_tab"  /> 

</LinearLayout>
```

So as you can see it's a regular layout with three buttons "simulating" tabs.

The contents of the tabs is also dictated by a ViewSwitcher:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ViewSwitcher xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:id="@+id/profile_view_switcher"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:inAnimation="@anim/fade_in_300"
              android:outAnimation="@anim/fade_out_300"
              android:background="@color/white">

<include
    android:id="@+id/profile_loading"
    layout="@layout/loading_view_full" />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/profile_content_list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
    android:divider="@null"
    android:dividerHeight="0dip"
    android:fadingEdge="none" />

</ViewSwitcher>
```

That shows a loading wheel and then switches to the listview. There is no other scrollable ViewGroup.

And that's basically it.

Now if you wanted to make the WHOLE thing scroll, then you need to use a custom adapter and set the above layout as the Header (or at least use getItemType in the adapter in a clever way). That way the whole screen is a List (with all the optimizations a list has).

We (ab)use this in the new 8tracks App under dev. ;)

Comment: It's awesome to have an answer from the author! This is so clever and I really appreciate it. Although I've finished my project (by giving up on using the header part), I'm sure this will be useful for me in the future (and for others too!) Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the following on your listview.

```
listview.addHeaderView(v);
```

Also rememeber, you must call this method before calling setAdapter() on your listview.

include your linearlayout where you have the user details and the tabs and add it as a header to the list.

Comment: It's a shame I never learned about this, so thank you for enlightening me. But sadly this doesn't suit my need either because actually only one of my tab contains a ListView and others contain GridView and LinearView, hence I have to add each of them as a fragment to the tabs instead of adding the tabs as header of the ListView.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to make the profile and the tabs the header of the listview, then updating the contents of the listview when the tabs are pressed. I don't know if you want the tabs to disappear from view as you scroll, though.

Comment: This is sort of confusing for me, because not all of my tabs contain a listview. What should I do if, say, the first tab has a `LinearLayout` and only the other two have `ListView`?

Answer (score 0):

According to the UI guide lines and best practices, it is advisable not to use Scrollable content inside Scrollview and doing that prevents the scrolling of the Scrollable content.

When you put two scrollview android just get confused which scroll view is touched. So sometimes it gets unable to deliver touch event.

But if still you want to achieve the scrolling functionality you can manage it by using the onTouch event of the particular view. And you need to design your layout accordingly.

But even if the requirement forces you to make such layouts. Try this…

Say case is somewhat like this….

```
  <ScrollView android:id=”@+id/parent_scroll” 
        android:layout_width=”fill_parent”
        android:layout_height=”wrap_content”
        android:layout_weight=”1″
        android:background=”@drawable/dotted_bg”
        android:focusableInTouchMode=”false”>
                    <LinearLayout   />
                    <LinearLayout   />
                    <LinearLayout  >
                    <ScrollView android:id=”@+id/child_scroll”  
                    android:layout_width=”fill_parent”
                    android:layout_height=”fill_parent”
                    android:background=”@drawable/text_box_bg”>
                <TextView android:id=”@+id/text_description”
                    android:layout_width=”fill_parent”
                    android:layout_height=”fill_parent”
                    android:textColor=”@color/gray”
                    android:textSize=”12dip”
                    android:padding=”5dip”
                    android:scrollbars=”vertical”/>
                <!–ScrollView>
              </LinearLayout>
```

**Step 1 : Provide unique id to both the scrollview.**

**Step 2 : get reference of that two scrollview in your activity.**

> ```
>   parentScroll=(ScrollView)findViewById(R.id.parent_scroll);
>     childScroll=(ScrollView)findViewById(R.id.child_scroll);
> ```

**Step 3: Now set touch listeners for both.**

> ```
>   parentScroll.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
>             public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
>                 Log.v(TAG,”PARENT TOUCH”);
>   findViewById(R.id.child_scroll).getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
>                 return false;
>             }
>         });
>         childScroll.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
>             public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) 
>             {
>                 Log.v(TAG,”CHILD TOUCH”);
>                                     // Disallow the touch request for parent scroll on touch of child view
>                 v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
>                 return false;
>             }
>         });
> ```

I hope it will help you.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer, but I think you misunderstand my question (maybe that's my fault because the title seems misleading). What I want to achieve is to be able to scroll the whole page, not just part of the page, hence disabling the parent scroll to make the child one scrollable is like adding a listview within an linearlayout, which is not desirable for me.

Comment: What you exactly want to achieve ? Do you want your ListView & Whole layout make scrollable ?

Comment: I've just edited my question and also the title, so please check it out. Also, if you have any suggestion for better design, I'll be even more appreciated.